# Partial derivation of $xy \log (1+ \sqrt{x^2 + 2y^2})$

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives, logarithms

Let $p: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$  with $p(x,y):= xy \log (1+ \sqrt{x^2 + 2y^2}) $

I want to find the set of points $D$, in which this function is partially differentiable and calculate its partial derivatives and gradient there.

So I would write:

$D(p)=\{(x,y) \mid x,y \in \mathbb{R^{+}} $}

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = xy \log (1+ \sqrt{x^2 + 2y^2}) $$
When I tried to get the partial function in the internet, I got the following:

[image: For x]

and

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} = xy \log (1+ \sqrt{x^2 + 2y^2})$$
here I got that:

[image: For y]

I don't understand how though. Can someone explain how to get the partial derivative here?

Comment: Be careful with your notation. It appears you have a little bit of error in the notation, when taking the derivative (I mean the expressions with $p$). So apparently you have a function 
$$
f(x,y) = xy ~ \underbrace{\log{\left(1 + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \right)}}_{=g(x)}
$$
and you want to calculate the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. I would recommend starting with the suggested notation 
$$
f(x,y) = xy g(x) \Rightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = xy ~g'(x) + y ~g(x)
$$
and you can continue from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial derivative with respect to $x$ is computed by keeping $y$ constant; so you get
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=y\log(1+\sqrt{x^2+2y^2})+xy\frac{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2y^2}}}{1+\sqrt{x^2+2y^2}}
$$
with issues only at $(0,0)$, which you can solve yourself.

Similarly for the other partial derivative.